# How to get place information using Google Knowledge Graph using Latitude and Longitude ?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, wikidata-api, google-knowledge-graph

I want business description using `google API` or `wikidata API`. 
[image]

As shown in above image I want to access description (which is highlighted in red circle.) and store it into application database.

**What I tried till now,** I used `google place API` to get the place information, using that I am able to get information like review,rating,opening hours. But I am not able to get that information which I have mention in above image. But I do not know how to get that information using `Wikidata api` or `Google Knowledge Graph api`.

Can any one suggest me that how can I use that API to get that information.

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Thanks,

Comment: Why downvote ? add comment please

Answer (score 0):

I'd also be keen to know if this is possible. For example, with a bounding box. 4 coordinates, might it be possible for Google Knowledge or another API to give me a summing up of the place.

For example: bbox=4.721375,52.290843,5.070190,52.399905

Might return information and history on the city of Amsterdam. Like when you type into Google Search "Amsterdam".

Just a thought. I have previously accomplished this with a very manual combination of Overpass API (related to OSM) and Freebase.

---

I just found this: [Find a place description in Freebase using latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469936/find-a-place-description-in-freebase-using-latitude-and-longitude)

So, it can be done. And it is already documented.